# Old version chrome(v48), is there a chromedriver fit to old chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, 32-bit, windows-embedded

I have a conditional environment for chrome(it version must be v48 for my company rules.)

But I can't find chromedriver for that version(v48 chrome).

please tell be the way for use that.

> OS : Windows embedded standard SP3.

when my program call a chromedriver(for selenium) in a code,
I got a error message

`the procedure entry point EventRegister could not be located Advapi32.dll`

Answer (score 1):

You can find older versions in https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. According to the [notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt) `ChromeDriver v2.21` support Chrome 48.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are looking for the compatible *ChromeDriver* for *Chrome v48*:

- As per the *Release Notes* of [chromedriver=2.20](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.20/notes.txt):

> Supports Chrome v43-48

- As per the *Release Notes* of [chromedriver=2.21](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/notes.txt):

> Supports Chrome v46-50

You can download [chromedriver=2.20](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20/) and [chromedriver=2.21](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/) from these locations.

---

### A word of caution

Though *chromedriver=2.20* and *chromedriver=2.21* would be compatible with *chrome=48.0* but both the binaries won't be compatible with the current release of **Selenium v3.141.59**.

---

### Solution

The best approach would be to ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))

Comment: your caution is soooooo helpful. Thanks!!